# How to not pass arguements and still make the function work?

Tags: javascript

```
function drawLine(ctx, sX, sY, eX, eY, sRGB, fRGB, lWidth, capStyle)
{
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(sX, sY);
    ctx.lineTo(eX, eY);
    ctx.lineWidth = lWidth||5;
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(49, 129, 48)';
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

And then I want to call the function like this:

```
drawLine(ctx, 50, 50, 100, 100, someStrokeStyle, someFillStyle, someCapStyle);
```

As you can see I have skipped the `lWidth` parameter. I want the function to still work, even when the `lWidth` is not passed as a parameter. How will I do this? Atm, it might think that the `someCapStyle` is the `lwidth`.

Comment: you missed one parameter in the arguments thats what i see. How can i know thats  lWidth parameter

Comment: @555k yes exactly, how would the function still work when I chose not to give in a parameter.

Comment: You are not using arguments fRGB and capStyle. So if you miss one, then function will get called with capStyle=undefined. your lWidth value will be someCapStyle

Comment: @555k Yes and how would I manage to tell the function that I want a default value for lWidth and someCapStyle for capStyle

Comment: if you want the function to work with lWidth as an optional parameter make it the last argument in function prototype

Comment: @555k But I am going to call this function many times. Sometimes, I will not specify lWidth, other times I will not specify capStyle.

Comment: then better use objects.. see below answers. i  think there is no other solution

Comment: @555k - There is another solution - specialization. Read about [The Three Projections of Doctor Futamura](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2009/05/three-projections-of-doctor-futamura.html "A Neighborhood of Infinity: The Three Projections of Doctor Futamura"). Someone has already written a JavaScript library to help you with it. It's called [Jeene](http://blog.higher-order.net/2008/09/14/jeene/ "Jeene: An automatic partial evaluator for JavaScript | Higher-Order").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a big amount of arguments to pass into a function like you have, use an object:

```
function foo({param1: val1, parma2: val2}) {}
```

In that case you wont be depend on number of arguments and order of them being represented.

So you can rewrite your function:

```
 function drawLine(drawObj)
{
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(drawObj.sX, drawObj.sY);
    ctx.lineTo(drawObj.eX, drawObj.eY);
    ctx.lineWidth = drawObj.lWidth||5;
    ctx.strokeStyle = drawObj.sRGB;
    ctx.lineCap = drawObj.capStyle;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you don't pass any argument, `undefined` value is passed instead, so just check in the function whether the argument has been passed or not:

```
if(typeof argument == "undefined") 
{ 
   argument = "default value";
}
```

So to not pass `lWidth`, just pass `undefined` as its value

P.S. the best way is to use a single argument `args`, which will be object containing all current parameters as properties.

Comment: Is there a way to just skip it completely, not even specify undefined?

Comment: @AnkurSharma yes. use if(argument)

Comment: @555k But it will think that the lWidth is defined, and capStyle is not defined. You see what I mean? Anyway, its ok, I will just use an object as shown by other answerers. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @AnkurSharma you can always test by yourself how javascript handles arguments: http://jsfiddle.net/BKkUE/. And to add to this answer read about undefined/null at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801032/why-is-null-an-object-and-whats-the-difference-compared-to-undefined

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to partially evaluate the `drawLine` function, assigning a constant value to `lWidth`. There's a JavaScript library called [Jeene](http://blog.higher-order.net/2008/09/14/jeene/) that does just this. This is how you would use it:

```
function drawLine(ctx, sX, sY, eX, eY, sRGB, fRGB, lWidth, capStyle) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(sX, sY);
    ctx.lineTo(eX, eY);
    ctx.lineWidth = lWidth || 5;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(49, 129, 48)";
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}

Function.prototype.specialize = net.higherorder.jeene.Jeene.make();

var drawLine2 = drawLine.specialize({
    lWidth: null // or whatever value you want
});
```

Then you use `drawLine2` as follows:

```
drawLine2(ctx, 50, 50, 100, 100, someStrokeStyle, someFillStyle, someCapStyle);
```

This is called specialization and is a very useful pattern. Read more about it: [A Neighborhood of Infinity: The Three Projections of Doctor Futamura](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2009/05/three-projections-of-doctor-futamura.html)

Comment: Will the function automatically know if someCapStyle is a capStyle and not lWidth.

Comment: @AnkurSharma - Yes, it will indeed. That's the really cool thing about specialization. Read the blog post to know exactly what's happening: http://blog.higher-order.net/2008/09/14/jeene/

Comment: What if both the arguments are string type? How would function know which one is correct? Could you explain in simple words? I am a newbie, sry about that.

Comment: @AnkurSharma - Specialization means that the name of the parameter is replaced by the value. Hence it won't confuse `lWidth` and `capStyle`. It's a form of partial evaluation. It's too much too explain in one comment. You should read it for yourself: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation

Answer (score 1):

You can put the optional parameter at the end of the paramter list. That way, if you leave it out, the other parameters won't be affected.

Another option would be to pass a single object with the attributes you want to define e.g.

```
function drawLine(options) {
    options.ctx.beginPath();
    options.ctx.moveTo(options.sX, options.sY);
    options.ctx.lineTo(options.eX, options.eY);
    // etc.
 }
```

Comment: This does not really solve the problem. If I do not specify the lWidth in the options object, the function will still fail. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, but you can test it for undefined.

Comment: Ok then. I thought there might have been a simpler way. But alright. thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use "function overloading" in Javascript, but here is a way to achieve what you want:

[How to overload functions in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855908/how-to-overload-functions-in-javascript)