# JavaScript Dynamic Arguments

Tags: javascript

Just curious. Is there a simpler/better way to write the following code? I need just two arguments options and callback. The function may be called without any argument, with just callback, or with an options hash and callback.

```
function () {
  if (typeof arguments[0] === "function") {
    callback = arguments[0];
  } else if (arguments[0] && typeof arguments[0] === "object" && typeof arguments[1] === "function") {
    options = arguments[0];
    callback = arguments[1];
  }
  ...
  ...

}
```

Comment: Your `else if` part misses a `typeof` check on `arguments[1]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to overload functions in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855908/how-to-overload-functions-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

```
function (options, callback) {
  if (typeof options === "function") {
    callback = options;
    options = {};
  }
  // code
}
```

Comment: But it does not check whether options is a hash, when callback is a function.