# How can I create a general function that can be called with different parameteres in this javascript example?

Tags: javascript

This is my JSFiddle to the incremental game: https://jsfiddle.net/y69sh3nc/

I have the function `getAutoClicker()`

```
var AutoClickers = 0;
var AutoClickerCost = 10;   

function getAutoClicker(){
   if(cookieClicks >= AutoClickerCost){
       AutoClickers++;
       cookieClicks -= AutoClickerCost;
       AutoClickerCost += Math.floor(AutoClickerCost*.3);
   } else{
       alert("Oh No!  It appears you do not have enough cookies to purchase an Auto Clicker.  An Auto Clicker currently costs "+AutoClickerCost+" which is "+(AutoClickerCost-cookieClicks)+" more cookies than you have.")
   }
}
```

I don't want to write another function for `getAutoClickerTwo()` because I don't want to repeat myself.

How can I write a function and use it for as many auto clickers as I want?

When I try to write a general function and call it with different paramenters for each button it does not work since the variables won't update in the other functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to overload functions in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855908/how-to-overload-functions-in-javascript)

Comment: Is the goal to activate a button 2 purchase 2 autoclickers with the same function?

Comment: Yes, I want the same function to be able to activate as many buttons as I want to add.

Comment: Sounds like you should define an `AutoClicker` class.

Comment: Why do you need another function? Is it to manage separate counters like `AutoClickers`/`AutoClickersCost`?

Comment: @Barmar Not necessarily a `class`, but using multiple objects and writing methods to work on them would be a good start indeed.

Comment: ok, but I need help to do this.

Comment: @Bergi True, but that's essentially what a class is, with just a little more organization to relate the objects and methods to each other.