# cypress Command overloading/overridding

Tags: cypress

I need suggestion on cypress framework
I am creating cypress automation for web application , this application has multiple modules/components , mostly dependent to each other. Preparing, overall E2E test scenario , where customs commands are called in workflow based on dependencies. But I also have plan to component wise tests, which should be standalone & run successfully without any dependencies.
Q. I have 2 components C1 and C2. Custom command for C2 uses element in C1 as assertion ; which works fine for E2E.
Cypress.Commands.add(‘add’, {(arg1,arg2)}
Need an idea how can I use same command for C2 as standalone. I was think of command overloading , may be like adding new parameter in command

```
Cypress.Commands.add(‘add’, {(arg1,arg2,arg3)}
If(arg3)
{
//donot use component 1 assertion #use something else without dependency
}
else
{
Use original command 
}
```

Will this work , is this similar to Parent.Child command? If yes can you provide me good example of how to use parent/child commands

Q2. Is there way to have parameters in test spec file, so tat I can pass argument to command

Comment: These two links can help:
[Overloading custom command in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68804196/overloading-custom-command-in-cypress)
[How to overload functions in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855908/how-to-overload-functions-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

There are numerous examples in the [Cypress Real World App](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/06/11/introducing-the-cypress-real-world-app/), [a payment application to demonstrate real-world usage of Cypress testing methods, patterns, and workflows](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app).

Several commands [demonstrate the use of parent and child commands that accept arguments](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app/blob/develop/cypress/support/commands.ts).

Comment: Just sharing a link doesn't suffice for an answer. Provide some examples alongside your link. I'm digging through this repo and do not see any example of, per say, overloading history navigation of window.location reasignment.