# Overloading custom command in Cypress

Tags: cypress

Can a custom command overload be done the same way as a function overload?
There is no answer to this in the documentation.

For example:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('navigateAndWaitForApi', 
  (relativePath: string, apisPath: string[], timeout?: number) => {

    let options = {};
    if (timeout !== undefined) {
      options = { timeout: TIMEOUT };
    }
    apisPath.forEach((api)=> {
      cy.intercept(`/api/${api}`).as(api);  
    })
    cy.visit(`/${relativePath}`);
    cy.wait(apisPath.map(apiPath => `@${apiPath}`), options);
});


Cypress.Commands.add('navigateAndWaitForApi', 
  (relativePath: string, apiPath: string, timeout?: number) => {
    cy.navigateAndWaitForApi(relativePath, [apiPath], timeout);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not appear so. The command name `navigateAndWaitForApi` is the total signature.

Add this after the command definitions

```js
console.log(Cypress.Commands._commands)
```

shows commands are stored in an object, keyed by the command name.

Adding the same command twice, the second overwrites the first.

---

It's possible to type-check the params at runtime.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('navigateAndWaitForApi', 
  (relativePath: string, apiPaths: string|string[], timeout?: number) => {

    if (typeof apiPaths === 'string') {
      apiPaths = [apiPaths]
    } 

    let options = {};
    if (timeout !== undefined) {
      options = { timeout: TIMEOUT };
    }
    apiPaths.forEach((api)=> {
      cy.intercept(`/api/${api}`).as(api);  
    })
    cy.visit(`/${relativePath}`);

    // cy.wait(apiPaths.map(apiPath => `@${apiPath}`), options);  // look dubious

    apiPaths.forEach(apiPath => {
      cy.wait(`@${apiPath}`), options)
    })

});
```

Comment: What you say makes sense. However, built-in commands have overloads and they claim that they are build using the same API calls.

Comment: **built-in commands have overloads** technically it's not different signatures, there is only one implementation for each command, but internally it resolves the arguments.