# How to override a class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Im trying to override a class with one that's in other file, the code works this way:
Page is loaded
One of the files containing the class is added to the head via:

```
let script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "./themes/" + thm + "/theme.js";
script.type = "text/javascript";
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

The content of the theme.js is the following:

```
class theme_obj{
    fn1(){
      console.log("Im thm1")
    }
    fn2(){
    }
}
var theme = new theme_obj();
```

So with the previous in mind, this is the problem.
What i want to do, is change the path of theme.js to other ones with the same structure to execute theme.fn1() and so on, but what I get is that theme.fn1() returns the value of the element that the webpage loaded with or was first added, and not the one that its "under use".

How do I fix it?
I have been looking for class override, function override, but nothing worked for me.
The temporal solution that I found is to reload the page whenever I change the theme but its not ideal

Comment: What is the code with which you change the path?

Comment: Strongly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855908/how-to-overload-functions-in-javascript

Comment: Where and when are you calling `theme.fn1()`? Please [edit] your question to show us that code. Notice that the script loads asynchronously!

Comment: @TravisJ as far as i can tell the question you sent is using JQuery

Comment: @Bergi i think you might be right, i will try and tell you, thx!!

Comment: jQuery? I encourage you to actually read the post.