# Can you override functions in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am new to ActionScripting but I have done some Java.  I was told they are kinda similar.  I am coding my swf file with some AS3 integrated.

```
function init():void{
  // do something
}

function init(var string:String):String{
  // do something else
}
```

is this not allowed in AS?  If not, is there another way of handling it besides?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to add, I ran this and got the error 1021: Duplicate function definition.  Sorry, should have added that in the initial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can override functions.  But the example you gave is not overriding - it's overloading.  For overriding a function, you basically just create a function with the same signature and everything in a subclass and add the word "override" right before it.

You can't directly overload a function though.  If you want a variable number of parameters, you have to use optional parameters instead.  Like this:

```
function init(str:String = null):String
{
    if (str == null)
    {
        // do one thing
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        // do another thing
        return "someString";
    }
}
```

And that's about the best you're going to be able to do in AS3.  The inability to overload functions, at least strictly speaking, is a fairly common complaint and obvious shortcoming of the language.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean method overloading?  Actionscript, sadly, does not support this.

To get around it, you can use default parameters, or just make your parameters a bit less constraining.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466683/how-can-you-overload-a-function-in-actionscript) has some details on that.

You could try this:

```
function init(var string:String = "Default value"):String{
  // do something 
}
```

Comment: overloading, Yes :-(.  Does it handle method overloading a different way or not at all.

Comment: @seroth Not at all. There may only be a single method with a given name. This is most likely because AS has high-level function types.

Answer (score 1):

Actionscript does not support method overloading. However, based on [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7466712/275643) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7466683/275643) you have other options.

> If you just want to be able to accept any type, you can use `*` to
>   allow any type:
>
> ```
> function someFunction( xx:*, yy:*, flag:Boolean = true )
> {
>   if (xx is Number) {
>     ...do stuff...
>   } else if (xx is String) {
>     ...do stuff...
>   } else {
>     ...do stuff...
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> If you have a large number of various parameters where order is
>   unimportant, use an options object:
>
> ```
> function someFunction( options:Object )
> {
>   if (options.foo) doFoo();
>   if (options.bar) doBar();
>   baz = options.baz || 15;
>   ...etc...
> }
> ```
>
> If you have a variable number of parameters, you can use the [`...`
>   (rest) parameter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#..._%28rest%29_parameter):
>
> ```
> function someFunction( ... args)
> {
>   switch (args.length)
>   {
>     case 2:
>       arr = args[0];
>       someBool = args[1];
>       xx = arr[0];
>       yy = arr[1];
>       break;
>     case 3:
>       xx = args[0];
>       yy = args[1];
>       someBool = args[2];
>       break;
>     default:
>       throw ...whatever...
>   }
>   ...do more stuff...
> }
> ```
>
> For cases where you need to call a common function to a number of
>   classes, you should specify the interface common to each class:
>
> ```
> function foo( bar:IBazable, flag:Boolean )
> {
>   ...do stuff...
>   baz = bar.baz()
>   ...do more stuff...
> }
> ```